# Highcharts stacked column dataLabels overlapping

Tags: charts, highcharts, overlap

I set the 'max' to '100' (for 100%) and 'min' to '0'.

[image]

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
[http://jsfiddle.net/3kVJS/2/]

Comment: You will have to increase height of chart container.

Comment: Does not work, @AntoJurkivic. Still, thanks for the help! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can

- increase height of chart
- set [minPointLength](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.column.minPointLength)
- use datalabels [y](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.y) parameter

Live demo will be hepful

Comment: Sorry @SebastianBochan, here is: jsfiddle.net/3kVJS/1/ 
The height is on maximum. 
Thank you!!

Comment: So at this moment it is fine for you or you need to add datalabels there?

Comment: I need add dataLabels, @SebastianBochan! 
I'm generating the chart as an image, with phantomjs.

Comment: As I see datalabels from jsfiddle works, but have you tried to set one of my suggestion ?

Comment: Yes, i have tried,but not working. Do you can post your working jsfiddle, please? Remembering that, i generate the chart as image with Phantomjs on Highcharts. Thank you, again!! ;-)

Comment: But if you have small columsn and limited height, where datalabels should be placed?

Comment: If there was an option to put DataLabel to the outside, as in the pie chart, it would be great!

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible, but you can request your suggestion here highcharts.uservoice.com